# overriding an implemented method from a base class

Tags: oop, overriding

Is it a good practice to override a base class method which already has an implementation in the base class?

If not, would it be okay to add a new method in the derived class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you are subclassing in order to create a new type that -- transparently to callers -- implements the methods of the supertype, then you can and should override the methods in the base class in order to implement them correctly in the context of the subclass.

Just make sure that callers working with base class instances can treat the subclass instances in the same way -- that your subclass implementation is consistent with the meaning of the methods in the superclass.

Without knowing more, it's not clear whether this gets at what you're asking, but I thought I'd take a crack at the question you asked. As such, I'll ignore the second question pending clarification as the answer to the first question is "Yes."

Comment: @DavidPCaldwell What I mean to ask is, wouldn't overriding an already implemented method modify base class behavior?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "modify." Instances of the derived class would of course do something differently than instances of the base class (if you didn't want that, you would not create a subclass in the first place). Instances that are members of the supertype but not the subtype would behave the same as always.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can most definitely be good practice, and is often times necessary. For example, you often want to *augment* the behavior of the base class's method as such:

```
// overriding method foo()

void foo() {
    // do something unique to the base class:
    println("called from child class!");

    // call parent class's implementation:
    super.foo();
}
```

Comment: wouldn't overriding an already implemented method in base class modify base class behavior?

Comment: @user793468 No; the base class knows nothing about its child classes.